# PostgreSQL + Yii 1.1: pg_attrdef pegando uma sequence de um schema errado

Tags: postgresql, yii

Estou setando minha sequence pra o schema public, assim:

```sql
ALTER TABLE legado.sys_pessoa ALTER COLUMN pess_codi SET DEFAULT nextval('public.main_code_seq')
```

Porém minha tabela pg_attrdef vem sempre com um valor sem o schema

```sql
SELECT pg_get_expr(adbin, adrelid)
FROM pg_attrdef
WHERE adrelid = 'legado.sys_pessoa'::regclass;
-- Retorna: nextval('main_code_seq'::regclass)
```

como podem perceber, vem sem o schema public, e eu preciso desse valor explicito nesse caso por causa do framework php q utilizo nesse meu sistema legado (YiiFramework 1.1) usa o valor default da tabela pg_attrdef.

Da forma que está, sem o schema public, o model do Yii fica tentando salvar com a sequence `legado.main_code_seq`, que não existe, pois ela ja está no public

O que eu poderia fazer? de último caso posso setar o valor da coluna pelo código PHP antes de salvar mas gostaria de uma solução mais concreta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr:** configure o search_path vazio antes de executar a `pg_get_expr` (`SET search_path TO '';`).

### Explicação

A função `pg_get_expr` tem a característica de ignorar o schema quando constrói a expressão em formato string caso o objeto referenciado esteja visível pelas regras do search_path, exemplo:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE teste_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE public.teste(id int DEFAULT nextval('public.teste_id_seq'));

CREATE SCHEMA outro_esquema;

CREATE SEQUENCE outro_esquema.teste_id_seq;

CREATE TABLE public.teste2(id int DEFAULT nextval('outro_esquema.teste_id_seq'));

SELECT adrelid::regclass, pg_get_expr(adbin, adrelid)
FROM pg_attrdef
WHERE adrelid IN ('public.teste'::regclass, 'public.teste2'::regclass);
```

A última consulta retorna:

```sql
 adrelid |                   pg_get_expr                   
---------+-------------------------------------------------
 teste   | nextval('teste_id_seq'::regclass)
 teste2  | nextval('outro_esquema.teste_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Agora, se mudarmos o `search_path`:

```sql
SET search_path TO outro_esquema;
```

O retorno muda:

```sql
    adrelid    |               pg_get_expr                
---------------+------------------------------------------
 public.teste  | nextval('public.teste_id_seq'::regclass)
 public.teste2 | nextval('teste_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Para que qualquer uma retorne com o esquema explícito, basta deixar o `search_path` vazio antes de executar a `pg_get_expr`:

```sql
SET search_path TO '';
```

Agora a consulta retorna o seguinte:

```sql
    adrelid    |                   pg_get_expr                   
---------------+-------------------------------------------------
 public.teste  | nextval('public.teste_id_seq'::regclass)
 public.teste2 | nextval('outro_esquema.teste_id_seq'::regclass)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, funcionou bem pra uma parte do meu sistema, setei o search path e funcionou por um momento, porém, no meu sistema, em uma mesma transaction eu uso algumas funções do schema public para setar alguns padrões de colunas e eu teria que refatorar muita coisa pra deixar explicito o schema dessas funções (a pior parte de mexer em sistema legado), acho q minha solução vai ser criar uma sequence espelhada e uma trigger pra atualizar a sequence principal, apesar de não solucionar meu problema, sua resposta responde minha pergunta então estou marcando ela como certa, valeu!!